# Should escaped strings be "unescaped" (MySQL, Node.js)?

Tags: mysql, string, node.js, escaping

I am working with the node driver for MySQL by felixge. Following the documentation

https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values

strings should be escaped *before* passed into the MySQL to avoid injection attacs.

My question is: should data be "unescaped" in some way *after* loaded from MySQL?

Currently, I have a problem with data integrity: I start with a string containing newlines. (printing with `console.log(string)` shows newlines in the console). After escaping the string, it is saved into a MySQL database. However, after the string is loaded back into memory, a `console.log(string)` shows escape codes `\n` instead of newlines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> before passed into the MySQL to avoid injection attacks.

This statement is wrong.
First, strings should be escaped because of syntax rules, not whatever injections.
Second, I hope they have some recipe for the non-strings too.

> Should escaped strings be “unescaped” (MySQL)

No.
Escaping is for the *query*, not database.

> shows escape codes \n instead of newlines.

you are escaping your strings twice then

Comment: Thanks! Good catch. I had an extra `util.inspect` which applied the extra escape codes just before printing the result. This had nothing to do with MySQL.